# How do I move one animation from one blender file to another one?

Tags: animation, rigging

Okay, so I have two separate blend files and both of them consist of a similar rigged character model with animations. However, one of them has an animation that I want both of them to share. Is there a means by which I can take the animation from one blender file and put it into the other one? Of course, I also don't know how I would go about giving a rigged character model an animation that was copied from another similar character but, I suspect that they're tutorials that cover that type of topic; the main issue here is that I don't know how to get the animation from one blender file to another.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rypC0KM6gs&ab_channel=LukasStratmann

Comment: @Emir: i watched the tutorial, which is good, but it does not describe how you move/link + assign the animation to an object. It only explains how you move/link it.

Answer (score 0):

In your new blender file, which shall be the target of your animation, you go to File->Append and choose your blend file.
Then open folder action and choose the animation you want to append.
Now select your target object which should get the animation and open NLA Editor and choose Add->include selected objects.

[image]

Then tap on Add again and choose your action. Done.

Comment: I partially followed the instruction and I got the desired result but, I don't think I knew what I was doing. I think what happened for me is that I already had my rig for the character selected and, so when I appended the animation for the other file, it just seem to automatically go into the rig. Also, is the NLA Editor the same as the Action Editor? I haven't heard of the NLA Editor. If there is any typo in this comment, I apologize in advance as I wrote it in a very tired state.

Comment: No problem i often follow tutorials in which I have no idea what I am doing but after you do this a few times, you will learn more and more what you are doing!maybe watch a tutorial about NLA. It’s a great helpful tool.